# How to include aspx code in page layouts?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout

In SP2013 I have several page layouts, which have the same html/controls code in each (in the .aspx file). Is there a way I can just do an `include` from another file?

Comment: Don't you reference a master page from the page layout template?

Answer (score 0):

iframe or web part, or just copy the code from each aspx file. You could include it in a javascript file and then just refer to the file from within the aspx pages.

Answer (score 0):

It's an asp.net simple solution. You need to create **User Control (.ascx)**. And in yout aspx page you refer to your User control(s).

There is a lot of documentation about user control ;)